# How to show installed app list in a listview without Checkbox getting unchecked when listview is scrolled?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, adapter

My goal is to display the list of installed apps in a custom listview (within an *Activity*) without checkbox getting unchecked (when listview is scrolled).

**The Problem**: *When Listview is scrolled, the checked status of the checkbox becomes unchecked.*

**My Progress So Far**:
While [this blog entry](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html) clearly shows how to get rid of the problem of checkboxes in listview getting unchecked, the difference is that it uses *Model* as the custom class whereas in my case it is a system class [i.e. the packageList1 = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);]

How can I resolve this? Below is my code attempt. I am able to successfully display apps in a listviw with checkboxes, just that checked status is getting unchecked when listview is scrolled.

**I AM OPEN TO ANY METHOD AS AN ANSWER THAT WILL ENABLE ME TO SHOW LIST OF INSTALLED APPS IN A LISTVIEW WITHOUT THE CHECKED STATUS OF CHECKBOXES BECOMING UNCHECKED**

*My Custom Listadapter class*:

```
public class Listadapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static String TAG = "focus";
List<PackageInfo> packageList;
Activity context;
PackageManager packageManager;
boolean[] itemChecked;

List<String> appNamestoBlock_local;

public Listadapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
        PackageManager packageManager, List<String> appNamestoBlock) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.packageList = packageList;
    this.packageManager = packageManager;
    this.appNamestoBlock_local = appNamestoBlock;

    itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];
}

private String getSerializedBlockedAppNames() {
    String serializedBlockedAppNames;
    Log.v(TAG,
            "-------- List<String> list = "
                    + TextUtils.join(",", appNamestoBlock_local));
    serializedBlockedAppNames = TextUtils.join(",", appNamestoBlock_local);
    return serializedBlockedAppNames;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView apkName;
    CheckBox ck1;
}

public int getCount() {
    return packageList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return packageList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.ck1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        holder.ck1.setFocusable(false);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);

    Drawable appIcon = packageManager
            .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
    String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
            packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
    appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
    holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
    holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
    holder.apkName.setText(appName);
    holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

    if (itemChecked[position])
        holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
    else
        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

    // Log.v(TAG,
    // "-------- checking in getView() in ListAdapter if appName is in getSerializedBlockedAppNames()");
    if (getSerializedBlockedAppNames().contains(appName)) {
        Log.v(TAG + " ListAdapter",
                "-------- YES, appName is in getSerializedBlockedAppNames(), appName = "
                        + appName);
        holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
    }

    holder.ck1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                itemChecked[position] = true;
            } else {
                itemChecked[position] = false;
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;

}

}
```

*In onCreate function of my main activity*:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);

Listadapter Adapter = new Listadapter(MainActivityCircularSeekbar.this, packageList1, packageManager, blockedApps);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Activity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AppScreen extends Activity {
private ListView list;
ArrayList<Datamodel> res;
MyAdapter _adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app_screen);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    List<PackageInfo> _myapps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    res = new ArrayList<Datamodel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _myapps.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = _myapps.get(i);

        Datamodel _model  = new Datamodel();
        _model.setAppname(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
        res.add(_model);
        System.out.println("ajajajja" + res.size() + res.get(i).getAppname());
    }
    _adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), res);
    _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setAdapter(_adapter);


}

}
```

## Datamodel class

```
public class Datamodel {

public String appname = "";
private boolean selected;

public String getAppname() {
    return appname;
}

public void setAppname(String appname) {
    this.appname = appname;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean isChecked) {
    this.selected = isChecked;
}

}
```

## Adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context _ctx;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public ArrayList<Datamodel> data;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Datamodel> _arraylist) {
    this._ctx = c;
    this.data = _arraylist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _ctx.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflator, parent, false);
    final CheckBox checks = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.b);
    final TextView _setappname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a);
    checks.setChecked(data.get(position).isSelected());

    Datamodel obj = data.get(position);
    _setappname.setText(obj.getAppname());
    checks.setTag(position);

    checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {                    
            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
            Datamodel _obj = data.get(getPosition);
            data.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
            String ss = _obj.getAppname();
            System.out.println("pos is" + getPosition);

        }
    });

    return itemView;
}

}
```

## Activity XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.installedapps.AppScreen" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

</ListView>
```

## Inflator xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.7" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you describe the code and tell us why your answer is great then i will give +1.@Dev Carlsberg

Comment: i am just saving the position of checked box using model class.

Comment: i am weak in description dude.

Comment: @DevCarlsberg - Thanks, your code does most of what I wanted from the question, but does not show the app icon in the listview. WOuld it be easy enough to add it by adding it to the *Datamodel* class?

Comment: I was able to add appIcon by adding a Drawable field to the Datamodel class. Thanks for the pointers here.