# ListView Holder check checbox Bug

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I'm developing an app with a custom layout and an **arrayAdapter**:

[image]

The problem is when I **check one Box** the app automatically check **another 2 boxes**!

I created a list where I put the positions of checkboxes and show that nothing its wrong! I think the problem is when I do the **recycle**!

Lets view some code; This is my ArrayAdapter:

```
class VivzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
Context context;
int[] images;
String[] titlesArray, descrptionArray;
List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

VivzAdapter(Context context, String[] titles, int[] images, String[] description) {

    super(context, R.layout.single_row, R.id.textView1, titles);
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
    this.titlesArray = titles;
    this.descrptionArray = description;
}

class MyViewHolder {
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView myTitle;
    TextView myDescription;
    CheckBox box;

    MyViewHolder(View v) {
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        box = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        // 1.ºtime
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //row contem RelativeLayout(root) em single_row.xml
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        //Log.d("VIVZ", "Creating a new Row");
    } else {
        //reciclamos aqui, qeremos usar antigo objecto holder
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
        //Log.d("VIVZ", "Recycling stuff");
    }
    holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    holder.myTitle.setText(titlesArray[position]);
    holder.myDescription.setText(descrptionArray[position]);
    holder.box.setTag(position);
    holder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    return row;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked){
        int position = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        positions.add(position);
        Log.d("VIVZ", "+ "+position);
    } else {
        int position = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("VIVZ", "- "+position);
        positions.remove(position);
    }
    Log.d("VIVZ", positions.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: What is the output of your logs ?

Comment: The positions match and are correct!

Comment: try with  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512344/how-to-show-installed-app-list-in-a-listview-without-checkbox-getting-unchecked/23577344#23577344) code.i hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stucked in same problem and found the solution. 
Create a boolean array having size same as no. of elements in the list and initial value false for each list item. Then in getView set position in Id through setId for checkbox. Now set the value of checkbox from boolean array through setChecked method of checkbox. Add onClickListener for checkbox and in this listener change the value in boolean array not checkbox value directly. 
I hope this resolve your problem also.

Just replace your adapter class with this code :

```
class VivzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
Context context;
int[] images;
String[] titlesArray, descrptionArray;
List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<Boolean> arrChecked;

VivzAdapter(Context context, String[] titles, int[] images, String[] description) {

super(context, R.layout.single_row, R.id.textView1, titles);
this.context = context;
this.images = images;
this.titlesArray = titles;
this.descrptionArray = description;

// initialize arrChecked boolean array and add checkbox value as false initially for each item of listview
arrChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
arrChecked.add(false);
}
}

class MyViewHolder {
ImageView myImage;
TextView myTitle;
TextView myDescription;
CheckBox box;

MyViewHolder(View v) {
    myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    box = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
}
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
MyViewHolder holder = null;
if (row == null) {
    // 1.ºtime
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //row contem RelativeLayout(root) em single_row.xml
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
    row.setTag(holder);
    //Log.d("VIVZ", "Creating a new Row");
} else {
    //reciclamos aqui, qeremos usar antigo objecto holder
    holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    //Log.d("VIVZ", "Recycling stuff");
}
holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
holder.myTitle.setText(titlesArray[position]);
holder.myDescription.setText(descrptionArray[position]);

//set position as id
holder.box.setId(position);
//set onClickListener of checkbox rather than onCheckedChangeListener
holder.box.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();

            if (arrChecked.get(id)) {
                //if checked, make it unchecked
                arrChecked.set(id, false);
            } else {
                //if unchecked, make it checked
                arrChecked.set(id, true);

            }

        }
    });

    //set the value of each checkbox from arrChecked boolean array
    holder.box.setChecked(arrChecked.get(position));

return row;
}
}
```

Comment: i found the solution before you post your answer and both we reach the same point of view. I add an button with and an  edittext where you click and get checkbox index selected.

Comment: Can you share your code so that I will have the multiple solution of this problem.

Comment: yes no problem I will use drobox https://www.dropbox.com/s/4lggfcgoupwafy8/5ListViewHolderFINAL.zip

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `getView` method you should check if the current position is in the positions array or not, this should fix the problem

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            // 1.ºtime
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //row contem RelativeLayout(root) em single_row.xml
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
            holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            //Log.d("VIVZ", "Creating a new Row");
        } else {
            //reciclamos aqui, qeremos usar antigo objecto holder
            holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
            //Log.d("VIVZ", "Recycling stuff");
        }
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        holder.myTitle.setText(titlesArray[position]);
        holder.myDescription.setText(descrptionArray[position]);
        holder.box.setTag(position);
        holder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    ////// Here you should update the checlbox status by checking if the current index is in the position array or not ////////////
boolean isFound = false;
for(int i =0;i<position.size();i++){
if(positions.get(i) == position){ // this line might need casting
isFound = true;
break;
}
holder.box.setChecked(isFound);
}
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Update the checkbox status!  Whats the difference doing here or on on click listener? I update the status on the listener method. Can you be more specific! Please put some code

Comment: @Andre Check the updates please, sorry for not being specific

Comment: didn't work man! when I am scrolling lost all of the selected checkbox previously selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample project for ur problem. link to download complete project
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C9Pqrvc_CWZHFDcmxKR01rc3c/edit?usp=sharing