# How to handle the view recycling in ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

In my app I am using a custom `ListView` that contains an `ImageView`, a `TextView`, a Button and a `CheckBox`. The problem is that if I check the list item 0 the items 5 & 9 are also selected. I have gone through [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) article and tried to implement the system but to no avail. Below is the code I am using:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = convertView;
    item=items.get(position);
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_marine, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPic);
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        holder.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone);
        holder.address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
        holder.btnFav=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonFav);
        cbFav=holder.btnFav;
        holder.btnFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                DirectoryItem elem=(DirectoryItem) holder.btnFav.getTag();

                if(elem.isFav() && buttonView.isChecked()){// check if already added or deleted.
                    return;
                }
                if(!elem.isFav() && !buttonView.isChecked()){
                    return;
                }
                elem.setFav(buttonView.isChecked());
                if(isChecked){
                    AddToFavourites add=new AddToFavourites(context, cbFav);
                    add.execute(String.valueOf(elem.getId()));
                }else{
                    RemoveFromFavourites remove=new RemoveFromFavourites(context, cbFav);
                    remove.execute(String.valueOf(elem.getId()));
                }

            }
        });
        holder.btnFav.setTag(item);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    loader.displayImage(item.getImgUrl(), holder.pic, options);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.phone.setText(item.getPhone());
    holder.address.setText(item.getAddress());

    holder.btnFav.setChecked(item.isFav());
    firstTime=false;
    return view;
}
```

Am I missing something here? Please help me with your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

### Edit:

I changed the code as above, now it is displaying a weird behavior. The Item I check doesn't remain checked after it goes out of the view. Instead some other item becomes checked. Also I have a question - I am maintaining an `ArrayList` of `DirectoryItems` which contains a boolean specifying if the item is selected or not. Can't I just use that to access the state of the `CheckBox` instead of putting it in the tag and accessing it from there? If not why is that so because it seems so counter intuitive to do it in such a roundabout way.

Comment: You can try [this](http://robinhood87.blogspot.in/2013/03/getview-method-wierd-in-listview-its.html)

Comment: I think , this is the exactly you are looking for  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706957/listview-holder-check-checbox-bug/23711226#23711226

Comment: I used toasts to display the data in the directoryitem contained in the checkbox tag and I noticed that the tags are not being maintained properly. first two or three tags are recurring again and again. Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the holder.btnFav.setTag(item); which is in the if portion also needs to be put in the else portion

```
 holder.btnFav.setTag(item);
    view.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.btnFav.setTag(item);
}
```

because the checkbox is recycled and the tag has to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your `items` structure is not refreshing after clicking on a checkbox. Check that `item.isFav()` is correctly filled

Answer (score 0):

> you have to persist the check box state in the list by ... maintain
>   field  boolean isChecked; in **items--> arraylist**. and check the state
>   ...in **getView(..)**

```
getView(){
.......
  holder.btnFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            items.isChecked=isChecked;
            if(isChecked){
                ..........
            }else{
                .............
            }
        }
    });
holder.btnFav.setChecked(items.isChecked);
......
}
```