# Displaying and ArrayList of LinearLayout objects in a ListView by extending ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have an ArrayList of LinearLayouts.  Each LinearLayout contains several other views that have been programatically added.

What I want to do is display these LinearLayout views in a ListView so to utilise the ability of a ListView to render only what is needed.

My original code used a ScrollView that was defined in the layout xml and i programatically added each of my LinearLayouts to the ScrollView and it worked fine.

I've now replaced the ScrollView in the xml with a ListView and i've added an adapter.

In the example below i've simplified everything to try and get to the root of the issue.  I get a ClassCastException when the getView method of the adapter returns the LinearLayout.

Activity layout xml (trend_scrollable.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ListView
              android:id="@+id/trend_listview"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
         </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for each row (simple_chart_item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chartItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
    public class ChartArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>
    {
        ArrayList<LinearLayout> layoutList;

        public ChartArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LinearLayout> list)
        {
            super(context, R.layout.simple_chart_item, list);
            this.layoutList = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>(list);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            return layoutList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return this.layoutList != null ? this.layoutList.size() : 0;
        }
    }
```

Activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.trend_scrollable);

    ListView layout = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.trend_listview);

    ArrayList<LinearLayout> layoutList = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        layoutList.add(getDemoView(GlobalVars.getContext(), i));            
    }

    ChartArrayAdapter adapter = new ChartArrayAdapter(this, layoutList);
    layout.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?  I've simplified the getView method of the adapter to always just return a LinearLayout view and i think this means that a new view will always be created.  I suspect maybe there is something wrong with returned LinearView and matching it with "simple_chart_layout.xml", maybe..

Comment: The answer in this thread has a good complete example of a custom listview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512344/how-to-show-installed-app-list-in-a-listview-without-checkbox-getting-unchecked

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of ListView is two-fold: view creation on demand, and view recycling. Creation on demand avoids having to create all of the Views up front when you are only going to show a portion of them at a time. View recycling avoids having to keep all those views in memory as the user scrolls the list.

Right now you are creating a whole bunch of views in `onCreate` and storing them in the adapter, which defeats both of the above purposes entirely. This is not really any better than what you did before with the ScrollView.

What you would typically do is give the adapter some data (like a List of Strings), and it would logically bind that data to the views on demand. In `getView()`, you would create the row layout (either by inflating a brand new one or re-using the provided `convertView` argument), populate it with the data, and return it. Looks something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater; // initialize in adapter's constructor

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate if not recycled
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_list_item, container, false);
    }

    // populate the views
    TextView sampleText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id...);
    sampleText.setText(...); // based on position argument and what data your adapter holds

    return convertView;
}
```

This is the basic version; normally you would also use the [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) to improve performance by eliminating the need for the `findViewById` calls.

I always recommend to people to watch [The World of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&ei=4xKEU5POKcbboASs3oLYCA&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=0k7wKMokvyNe-3GY29Ajfw). You seem to have some experience already with Android, but you may find it helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  You've said that my implementation is far from ideal which is correct.  The link to the google tutorial on youtube filled in some gaps in my understanding.  My thinking was based on taking iterative steps from building all views for a scroll view to a properly implemented list view so my question was about why this example didn't work.  You can create any view you like (programatically so not restricted to the xml layout) and return it.  My answer solves my problem.  I will now progress to building each view as needed (as suggested) then to using ViewHolder patterns.

Comment: You can certainly create the Views programmatically, but you should still be re-using the recycled `convertView` when it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I got my example to work after properly looking through the debug messages.  What i was doing was creating a demo LinearView using the code below:

```
private static LinearLayout getDemoView(Context context, int i)
{
    LinearLayout containerView = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams containerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    containerView.setLayoutParams(containerParams);
    containerView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TextView titleLabelView = new TextView(context, null);
    titleLabelView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    titleLabelView.setText("Demo text view 1 - " + Integer.toString(i)); 
    containerView.addView(titleLabelView);

    TextView bodyLabelView = new TextView(context, null);
    bodyLabelView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    bodyLabelView.setText("Demo text view 2 - " + Integer.toString(i)); 
    containerView.addView(bodyLabelView);

    return containerView;
}
```

This code simply creates a LinearView and puts two TextViews inside which have some text.

The error i got in LogCat was:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

By commenting out the following lines my code worked:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams containerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
containerView.setLayoutParams(containerParams);
```

The rest of the code is:

Adapter:

```
public class ChartArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>
{
    public ChartArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LinearLayout> list)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.simple_chart_item, list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return this.getItem(position);
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.trend_scrollable);

    ListView layout = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.trend_listview);

    ArrayList<LinearLayout> layoutList = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        layoutList.add(getDemoView(this, i));            
    }

    ChartArrayAdapter adapter = new ChartArrayAdapter(this, layoutList);
    layout.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The problem was that i'd added LinearLayout params to a view that was going into a ListView.  Something that no-one but me would have known because I hadn't put that part of the code in my original question - my apologies.

What i've given here is a very poor implementation of a ListView as this was an intermediate step in going from a ScrollView where I had all the LinearViews already created to a ListView where the views get created on the fly by the adapter.  This exercise has been useful to me but is not likely useful for anyone else although it does prove you can pass an arraylist of anything you like to a custom adapter then create whatever view you like when returning from getView.