# How to display installed app detail (label name, icon) in list view using array adapter?

Tags: android

I am brand new to programming, and specially to android. I am trying to get all the installed application details, such as the label name and the icon to be displayed in a list view, and to launch it when a particular app is been clicked.. Currently I am trying to work with how to display them. i tried many of the source codes available in the net. Finally i ended up using this code which  I got from this site, http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon. It seems to work but the output i get in the emulator is kind of weird..

I am kind of confused not knowing what to do.

My code:

```
public class SecondPage extends ListActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity" ;
ListView lv;
ArrayList al;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    lv = getListView();

    al = getPackages();
   lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al));

}

class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.v(TAG, appname + "\t " + pname + "\t " + versionName + "\t " + versionCode);
    }
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}
private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is one line of the list view i get in the emulator:

`com.example.sample3.app.$PInfo@b3ec49c0`

Comment: `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` contains only a single textview. Make your own custom layout for displaying further details.

Comment: thank you for your comment. i'll try with what u suggested.  but my actual problem is as i mentioned before "com.example.sample3.app.$PInfo@b3ec49c0" keeps repeating for the entire listView except for the last 8 characters. I wanted to know what that is? and what should i do to display the actual name of the apps and get their package name to launch it

Comment: check[this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512344/how-to-show-installed-app-list-in-a-listview-without-checkbox-getting-unchecked/23577344#23577344) to get app names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `getPackages()` method with the following code

```
private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    ArrayList<String> appName = new ArrayList();
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
        appName.add(apps.get(i).appname);
    }
    return appName;
}
```

A new `ArrayList` of type `String` is used to store the `appnames` and this list is being given to the `ListView`

Hope this helps you.