# Adding button in custom adapter class in android

Tags: android, button, custom-adapter

Hi in my application I am parse the json url and displaying the image and text Now I am going to adding the button. if i click the button i want to move to another activity.Now My problem is if i click the button nothing happened .can any one please help me.

ListViewAdapter class:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        ImageLoader imageLoader;
        HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

        public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
            this.context = context;
            data = arraylist;
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Declare Variables
            TextView title;

            ImageView thumb_url;


            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
            // Get the position
            resultp = data.get(position);

            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);

            // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
            thumb_url = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

            // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
            title.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TITLE));

            // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
            // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.THUMB_URL), thumb_url);
            // Capture ListView item click
            Button Add = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Get the position
                    resultp = data.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                    // Pass all data rank
                    intent.putExtra("title", resultp.get(MainActivity.TITLE));
                    // Pass all data country
                    /*intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
                    // Pass all data population
                    intent.putExtra("population",resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
                    */// Pass all data flag
                    intent.putExtra("thumb_url", resultp.get(MainActivity.THUMB_URL));
                    // Start SingleItemView Class
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }

                private void startActivity(Intent in) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                private Context getApplicationContext() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return context;
                }

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            return itemView;
        }

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
            }
```

listview_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#444"
        android:padding="3dp" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <!--  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
 -->

  <!--   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag"
        android:padding="1dp" />
 -->

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/add"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/rank"
         android:text="Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        // Declare Variables
        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ListView listview;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
        static String TITLE = "title";
        /*static String COUNTRY = "country";
        static String POPULATION = "population";*/
        static String THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Get the view from listview_main.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
            // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }

        // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Create an array
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                jsonobject = JSONfunction
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://indianpoliticalleadersmap.com/android/DemoSchool/json/json_item.php");

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("veg_food");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                        /*map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                        map.put("population", jsonobject.getString("population"));*/
                        map.put("thumb_url", jsonobject.getString("thumb_url"));
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
                // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Show me your `listview_item.xml` file

Comment: Try to add your code on public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

Comment: hi i posted my listview_item.xml

Comment: which activity you want to start, is it SingleItemView or MainActivity, why you are starting two activities in your code at the same time, elaborate what exactly you want

Comment: I am displaying data by using json url i.e in MainActivity and after hat i added one button called add if i click the add button i want to move to another activity

Comment: can you please edit my code and tell me

Answer (score 0):

Store the hashMap in the view tag.

```
Button Add = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
Add.setTag(resultp);
```

Then access it inside onClick() like this

instead of trying to access it by position which may not refer to the current view, access it by its tag. In your code, replace the line

```
resultp = data.get(position);
```

with

```
resultp = (HashMap<String, String>) view.getTag();
```

EDIT: After adding `resultp = data.get(position);` as shown above
Replace your onClick() with the following

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    resultp = (HashMap<String, String>) view.getTag();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", resultp.get(MainActivity.TITLE));                    
    intent.putExtra("population",resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
    intent.putExtra("thumb_url", resultp.get(MainActivity.THUMB_URL));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You may also check similar question [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257093/in-custom-list-view-check-box-is-unchecked-when-i-scrolling/24257419#24257419)

Comment: how to store view tag in hashmap can you please tell me

Comment: Add this line  `Add.setTag(resultp);`.  Now the resultp(which is HashMap) is accessible from the view using `view.getTag()`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you add `MainActivity` code if this not worked for you? I think you want to navigate to the `SingleItemView activity` not to `MainActivity`.

Comment: even json data also not displaying it's showing error

Comment: Hi I posted my MainActivity Class can you please tell me What i did mistake