# Listview checked items disappear after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-listview

I have implemented the listview and I am able to store the checked list items as well. But when I rotate the device the selections made in the listview disappear.

How do i fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: We need more information. Please provide a minimal code example that recreates the issue you are asking about.

Comment: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512344/how-to-show-installed-app-list-in-a-listview-without-checkbox-getting-unchecked/23577344#23577344), may be you will get some help.

Comment: also you have to use onSavedInstanceState() for saving the positions and onRestoreInstanceState() to get save positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the screen rotates your activity is recreated. When it is recreated any changes that was made on the list is not reciprocated. The simplest way to retain checked state is to use a bundle to save checked positions in **onSavedInstanceState()** method. This is called before the orientation change happens and your activity is destroyed. Then you can restore to previous state in **onCreate()** or **onRestoreInstanceState()** methods.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to add:
 `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`- in the manifest of the activity

Comment: That is not the best way, and [is not recommended](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange), as there are several other configuration changes that can occur to recreate your activity, as well as your activity just being in the background too long (android will save your activity state and destroy it to be recreated later).