# How to check the play store catrgory of installed app in android

Tags: android, google-play, categories

i am not able to show the play store category of installed apps in android.

final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);

Comment: More information will be needed. Also provide relevant code that you tried. The category in your code doesn't have anything to do with the Play Store category.

Comment: [Have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512344/how-to-show-installed-app-list-in-a-listview-without-checkbox-getting-unchecked/23577344#23577344)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Android that tracks "the play store category of installed apps". After all, Android apps do not have to be installed via the Play Store.

Comment: i think it possible please check this link. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1419810. this app have the functionality as similar that i want to do

Comment: @surendrasingh: No, it does not: "...we decided to propose an app to build an open database for app categorization and offer an API to easily access the available data. The use of the API and associated database is demonstrated within the app CatApplus (see the associated thread). The app helps to build and consolidate this API and database. How does CatApplus works: it retrieves all your apps; it uses our API to retrieve associated categories from our database; it stores all data in the application database for offline use and propose you categories via folders".